# Typeahead and Laravel not returning any results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to setup Typeahead.js, to use as an autosuggestion feature on my Laravel app. Unfortunately, it returns no results, each time.

I return the data beforehand to take advantage of local storage, so there is no querying the DB in my instance.

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome', ['treatments' => Treatment::orderBy('treatment')
        ->pluck('treatment', 'id')]);
});
```

**Welcome view:**

```
const treatments = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: '{{$treatments}}'
  });

  $('#bloodhound').typeahead({
      hint: true,
      highlight: true,
      minLength: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'treatments',
      source: treatments,

      templates: {
        empty: [
          '<div class="list-group search-results-dropdown"><div class="list-group-item">Nothing found.</div></div>'
        ],
        header: [
          '<div class="list-group search-results-dropdown">'
        ]

      }
    }).on('typeahead:selected', function (evt, item) {
    $('#bloodhound').text(item.id);
  });
```

**Input field:**

```
<input type="search" name="treatment" id="bloodhound" class="form-control" 
        placeholder="Find a treatment" autocomplete="off" required>
```

**Output of `$treatments` array:**

```
local: '{&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Treatment 1&quot;}'
```

The last section of the script, should enter the value of the selection (ID ) within the input field, but unfortunately that doesn't work either.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't string `local: '{&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Treatment 1&quot;}'` seem strange to you?

First, it is sent through `htmlspecialchars` and all your quotes became `&quote;`, second - value of `local` is a string. Do you think, typeahead can understand what you have here?

Solution: get your elements form database and output'em json-encoded. To avoid quotes escaping use `{!! !!}`:

```
const treatments = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: {!! $treatments !!}
});
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view(
        'welcome', 
        ['treatments' => Treatment::orderBy('treatment')->pluck('treatment', 'id')->toJson()]
    );
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, avoiding the quotes escaping now produces something more meaningful: local: '{"2":"Treatment 1"}}' It still cannot be found though when I search for it @u_mulder?

Comment: Remove single quotes from beginning and end of `$treatments` in a view.

Comment: `local: {!! $treatments !!}` is what I have now within the script. Is this what you meant @u_mulder?

Comment: Yes, I meant it.

Comment: Ok, it still doesn't return the result unfortunately.

Comment: As I see in typeahead manual you need `local` to be array, isn't it?

Comment: Sample snippet of what it is now: ```const treatments = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: [{"2":"Treatment 1"}]
  }); ```

Comment: No, it should be just `local: ["Treatment 1"]`, without keys.

Comment: I want to include the key within the value of the input field once a user has selected their choice - so I can then save it correctly within the DB. In order to do that I guess I need to include the keys as well?

Comment: In this case you do. But next you should create a template how your data will be showed.